# MySQL server has gone away Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.ph

Tags: magento2

Because so much was broken in a vanilla install of Magento by my ISP (e.g. I could not create categories, I was told to do this:

```
/usr/bin/php-7.1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

This ran for about 15 minutes with a lot of output, then ended with this:

> Import failed: Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone
>   away in
>   /var/sites/j/xxxxx.store/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 228

Is this normal?

linux, php 7.1, Magento version unknown as the site and control panel are now dead.

Comment: John, have you gotten past this hurdle?

Comment: No, I switched to woocommerce, but I expect the problem was that the DB was on another server, and magento didntly like the latency.  Increasing the timeouts may help

Comment: Is WooCommerce taking care of your requirements trouble free at this time?  If not please Open a new question since you are no longer using Magento2.  PS we also provide suggestions for WooCommerce MySQL configurations.  View profile, Network profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same issue and this was the solution to my problem:

> http://www.magentoformat.com/magento-2-mysql-server-has-gone-away-fix/